# jQuery, click an element inside its clickable container - how to override

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list o elements `li` that becomes my image carousel. Each element is a thumbnail, and it becomes clickable using jQuery because i needed to put the image as `li` `background-image`. This I can not change. When thumb click, it calls a lightbox to show the image passed as bg parameter.

```
<ul id="piclist">
    <li class="box" style="background-image: url('url_1');"><i class="seq" id="1"></i></li>
    <li class="box" style="background-image: url('url_2');"></li>
    <li class="box" style="background-image: url('url_3');"><i class="seq" id="2"></i></li>
    <li class="box" style="background-image: url('url_4');"></li>
</lu>
```

The piece of my jQuery code to do this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.box').click(function() {
        return $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
</script>
```

IT WORKS! But in some special cases, the thumbnail must show a kind of button, so I used a positioned `<i></i>` because of the Font Awesome im using in the project.

The image bellow can illustrate what im talking about:

[image]

**THE PROBLEM IS:**

When the `li` loads an `i` element, it also must be clickable, and its link must override his parents link - the container.

I did a piece of code in jQuery to do this, but always when I click on the `i` element button, the action loads the image lightbox from the `li`. Its wrong. It should do another action, for example, open an URL in new window, load another modal, whatelse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.box').click(function() {
        return $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
    $('.seq').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("id")); //IT WORKS!
            *do other action...* //Doesn´t work, open the <li> lightbox!
    });
</script>
```

Any Help? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the $('.seq') click to this:

```
$('.seq').click(function(ev) {
   ev.stopPropagation();

   console.log($(this).attr("id")); //IT WORKS!
   *do other action...* //Doesn´t work, open the <li> lightbox!
 });
```

This will prevent the click event from bubbling up an triggering the click even of the i's parent (the li). Notice I added the event object as an argument and I'm calling the stopPropagation (http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method before doing anything else.

Comment: Hi Jose, it worked! Very fine and most simple impossible! hehehe

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. Would you mind accepting the answer as the correct one for this question?

Comment: Just the right little line of code at the right time - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if e.target is identical to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.box').click(function(e) {
        if( e.target !== this )  return;
        return $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
    $('.seq').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("id")); //IT WORKS!
        *do other action...* 
    });
</script>
```